# $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); returns correct data but $form->getData() returns null even after $form->submit($data)

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I'm using Angular and FOSRestBundle

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(resource) {
    console.log("url: " + this.url);
    console.log(resource);
    return this.http.post(this.url  + "?access_token=YjJkNWU0ZDE5NjgxNGM5MmYzYTYxOGY0YzNmZjgxNDAzY2QzNTA5MmI2NjEyMWMzMDhlM2NlM2JmYzk4ZGQ5Mg", JSON.stringify(resource));
  }

}
```

**console.log(resource)**

> Object { title: "gfdsfg", slug: "fdsd", storyline: "fgdsgfd", summary: "gfsfd", videoSource: "107", year: "2011", length: "44", status: "pending", poster: "data:image/png;base64,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…", wideImage: "data:image/png;base64,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…" }

As you can see Angular is sending the correct data.

**My controller action:**

```
/**
     * @FOSRest\Post("/documentary", name="create_documentary", options={ "method_prefix" = false })
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function createDocumentaryAction(Request $request)
    {
        $documentary = new Documentary();

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
        ];
        $form = $this->createForm(AdminDocumentaryForm::class, $documentary);
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form->submit($data);

        //return new JsonResponse($data, 200, $headers);
        //return new JsonResponse($form->getData(), 200, $headers);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return new JsonResponse($form->getData(), 200, $headers);
        } else {
            $errors = (string) $form->getErrors(true, false);
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 400, $headers);
        }
```

`return new JsonResponse($data, 200, $headers);` returns

> Object { title: "gfdsfg", slug: "fdsd", storyline: "fgdsgfd", summary: "gfsfd", videoSource: "107", year: "2011", length: "44", status: "pending", poster: "data:image/png;base64,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…", wideImage: "data:image/png;base64,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…" }

but `$form->getData()` returns this:

> Object {  }

`$form->submit($data);` doesn't seem to be working.

**AdminDocumentaryForm**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Documentary;
use App\Entity\VideoSource;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AdminDocumentaryForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('slug', TextType::class)
            ->add('storyline', TextType::class)
            ->add('summary', TextType::class)
            ->add('year', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('length', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('status', TextType::class)
            ->add('shortUrl', TextType::class)
            ->add('videoSource', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => VideoSource::class,
                'choice_label' => 'id',
            ])
            ->add('poster', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('wideImage', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'data_class' => Documentary::class,
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "admin_documentary";
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am missing, can you help?

Comment: Looking at the Symfony Documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) is there are reason you are using ->submit instead of ->handleRequest? Handle request will do the de-coding for you and simplify your code.

Comment: @MEmerson I tried using ```$form->handleRequest($request);``` but ```return new JsonResponse($form->getData(), 200, $headers);
``` still returns nothing.